# SQL DDL metadata into Spark schema metadata

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I can create a Spark `StructType` via DDL schema like so:

```
val ddl = "a STRING COMMENT 'max_length=1000'"
val schema = StructType.fromDDL(ddl)
```

This creates a schema where the field for column `a` looks like so:

```
StructField(
  name = "a",
  dataType = StringType,
  nullable = true,
  metadata = Metadata(Map("comment" -> "max_length=1000"))
)
```

After that, I can do something like this to put the comment as actual metadata:

```
val maxLengthMetadata = metadata.getString("comment") // max_length=1000
/*
String regex to grab elements individually e.g. 
key = "max_length" 
val = "1000"
*/
metadata.putString(key, val)
```

Is there a way to format `ddl` so the Metadata object can be populated like above without going through String manipulation after grabbing data from SQL comment? Something like this:

```
val ddl = "a STRING max_length='1000'"
```

So instead of

```
Metadata(Map("comment" -> "max_length=1000"))
```

I want

```
Metadata(Map("max_length" -> "1000"))
```

without having to go through the above roundabout way.

I've also tried running some scala code to see if I can put some metadata then run `StructField.toDDL` like so:

```
val metadata: Metadata = new MetadataBuilder()
  .putString("timestamp_mask", "yyyy-MM-dd")
  .build()

val schema = StructType(
  Seq(
    StructField("c", TimestampType, nullable = true, metadata)
  )
)

schema.fields.foreach(field => println(field.toDDL))
```

but this doesn't work either since `toDDL` depends on `metadata.getString("comment")`....

I don't see an easy way for DDL to support this kind of behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it's possible to do it using DDL string but you can use json schema instead. For example:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{DataType, StructType}

val jsonSchema = """{"type":"struct","fields":[{"name":"col1","type":"string","nullable":true,"metadata":{"max-length": 100}}]}"""
val schema = DataType.fromJson(jsonSchema).asInstanceOf[StructType]
println(s"${schema.fields(0).name} - ${schema.fields(0).metadata}") // col1 - {"max-length":100}
```